# How to flag (Enable / Disable) Flutter RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter

I want to flag my `RefreshIndicator` with a boolean param.

Is it possible? What is the trick? Because there are no many options...

```
return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () async {
        return Future.value();
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.pink,
    strokeWidth: 2.75,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(...)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To disable RefreshIndicator pass notificationPredicate function that returns false.

After doing that refresh indicator won't be shown or onRefresh called.

```
RefreshIndicator(
  notificationPredicate: enabled ? (_) => true : (_) => false,
  ...
);
```

Comment: Error: The argument type 'Future<bool> Function(ScrollNotification)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool Function(ScrollNotification)'.

Comment: This really works very well if you just remove `async`.  This should be the correct answer

Comment: Edited. The sample code must work now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean called `_showRefreshIndicator` and based on that either render `SingleChildScrollView` with `RefreshIndicator` or render only `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
return _showRefreshIndicator ? RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () async {
        return Future.value();
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.pink,
    strokeWidth: 2.75,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(...)
) : SingleChildScrollView(...);
```

Comment: In my opinion it's too messy. My `SingleChildScrollView` is too long to duplicate. Also forwarding everything into a function is also a bit messy. Thanks for the reply, if that's the only option, then I have no other choice.

Comment: Extract `SingleChildScrollView` in an another Stateless/Stateful widget.

Comment: Seems the only option. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure or aware if any other option exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ternary operator in the *onRefresh* function itself since ternary operators resolve to true or false you can set a boolean variable and toggle between behaviors in your *onRefresh* function like this.

```
bool refresh = true;
return RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () async {
        refresh ? return Future.value() : doSomeOtherThing;
    },
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.pink,
    strokeWidth: 2.75,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(...)
)
```

Comment: The problem is that It's not disappear my refresh icon. I want to disable it.